# In Java, how to print divisor numbers?

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, if-statement, printing

I want to print the divisors of a user input value between 1 and 10000.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Divisors {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Range;
        int Divisor;

        while(true) {

            System.out.print("Please insert a number between 1 and 10000: ");
            Range = scan.nextInt();

            if (Range < 1 || Range > 10000)
            System.out.println("Wrong choice");

            else
                break;
        }


        Divisor = 0;    // Start counting Divisor from Zero

        for (int loop = 1; loop <= Range; loop++) {
            if (Range % loop == 0)
                Divisor++;
                System.out.println("loop);      
            }

        System.out.println("Total number of divisors of " + Range + " is " + Divisor);

    }
}
```

> I have problem here with command **System.out.println("loop);**. 
>   I want to print all the divisors, like if a user inserted 10, then the
>   output should show something like:

!

```
Please insert a number between 1 and 10000: 10
1
2
5
10
Total number of divisors of 10 is 4
```

!
!

> But the current output is:

!

```
Please insert a number between 1 and 10000: 10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Total number of divisors of 10 is 4
```

!
!

> so how to print **loop** only when the **(Range % loop == 0)** is true??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the {}

```
for (int loop = 1; loop <= Range; loop++) {
    if (Range % loop == 0) {
       System.out.println(loop); 
       Divisor++;
    }     

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. I will read further about the solution.

Comment: You are welcome @MohammedHashim, if you have any question just ask. :-)

Answer (score 1):

just add brackets to if condition the  code can be as follows

```
  for (int loop = 1; loop <= Range; loop++) {
            if (Range % loop == 0){
                Divisor++;
                System.out.println("loop); 
               }     
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missed the `{}` in the loop :

```
for (int loop = 1; loop <= Range; loop++) {
    if (Range % loop == 0) {
       System.out.println("loop); 
       Divisor++;
    }     

}
```

When you write `if` condition and you have one line of code after it will be executed : (Witout `{}` )

```
 if (Range % loop == 0) 
           System.out.println("loop); //WORK !
           Divisor++; /// NOT WORK !!
```

But with `{}` the two line executed  :

```
if (Range % loop == 0) {
           System.out.println("loop); //WORK !
           Divisor++; /// WORK !!
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Any conditional statement will execute subsequent one line if you do not include curly braces. If you want to execute more than one statement inside if block, include those statements inside curly braces.
Example:

```
    If(Condition)
{
Statement1;
Statement2;
}
```